# Firefox requires authorization for Jquery-Get on same host

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wrote an extension that works both on Firefox and on Chrome. That extension injects some code on the page that also does a Get - Request on the same site.

I am on `https://example.com/Posts/1234` and try to call another url from the **same** host:

```
var docUrl=document.location.href;
$.get(docUrl + '/mentionable.json?q=test', function (response) {
// do something
});
```

(So the complete url called is `https://example.com/Posts/1234/mentionable.json?q=test`)
In the chrome extension this works just fine. When I try to run the same code as a Firefox web-extension instead I retrieve a `401 unauthorized` response. So my guess would be that chrome sends the authorization-cookie from the current visited site while Firefox does not.

Any way to tell Firefox to use the current authorization?

Comment: Can you try using `withCredentials` on the request? You'll need to restructure your `.get()` call to use `xhrFields`, see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: That did not help. I already tried the "Ajax-Way" including `withCredentials`. What DID help I already wrote as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Firefox requires the following entry in the permissions of the `manifest.json`:

```
"https://*/*"
```

(or the URL you want to connect to) even if it's the same host as the site the extension-js is on. Chrome works **without** this entry.